# Oracle max date issue

Tags: oracle, date, max

I'm trying to find the max(date) in the following select statements and getting errors...can someone please assist?

```
SELECT MAX(STMT_DATE) < STMT_CLOSE_DATE as "lastdate"
  FROM STMT_FACT;
```

Comment: what should `< STMT_CLOSE_DATE` do?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(STMT_DATE) as "lastdate"
FROM STMT_FACT
WHERE STMT_DATE < STMT_CLOSE_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
To get only Max date:-
  SELECT MAX(STMT_DATE) as "lastdate" FROM STMT_FACT WHERE STMT_DATE < STMT_CLOSE_DATE

To get complete row which contains latest date:-
  SELECT STMT_DATE as "lastdate", [Rest of the columns] FROM (SELECT STMT_DATE FROM 
  STMT_FACT WHERE STMT_DATE < STMT_CLOSE_DATE ORDER BY STMT_DATE DESC) WHERE rownum=1;
```